# How to tell JDeveloper to not create new Oracle Objects and use my one?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I connect to oracle db using adf, this db use custome objects in it's columns. So when i add new entity based on table, JDeveloper automatically generate this objects.

What i need to know is how to generate all types in one model project and then reuse thos domain objects in all other applications without regenerate it each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense what you are looking for, but I am afraid Jdeveloper doesn't support it. You can still achieve it by changing the sources manually, though - it will work.

Comment: You mean after i generate the entities i delete the generated types and point the attribute to my shared one ??